open an app without launcher icon form another app
I wrote an app without icon in launcher Android
Now I want from another app open without icon app.
But I don't know have do that. Can someone tell me? It's make me so happy. Thank you so much
I try under code but my app get crash
`intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.evolutionos.upgrade", "com.android.evolutionos.upgrade.MainActivity"));

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent);`


Can you [edit] your question and post more details about the crash? Is there something in logcat regarding the crash?
